Django DEBUG Logging doesn't print anything?
I'm currently working on implementing logging in my Django project, but I'm encountering an issue where calls to logger.debug('log') do not output anything. I suspect there might be something wrong with my logging configuration.
Below is the LOGGING configuration from my settings.py:
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug(f"debug from logger")
DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL = "DEBUG"
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    "formatters": {
        "verbose": {
            "format": "{levelname}: {message} ({process:d}:{thread:d}::{filename}:{lineno}::{asctime})",
            "style": "{",
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
        },
        "simple": {
            "format": "{levelname}: {message} ({filename}:{lineno})",
            "style": "{",
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'stdout': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
        "file": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "formatter": "simple",
            "filename": logs_path.joinpath(f"{STAGE}-django.log").as_posix(),
        },
        "mail_admins": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler",
            "include_html": True,
        },
    },
    'loggers': { 
        '': { 
            'handlers': ['stdout', 'file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['stdout', 'file'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        "django.request": {
            "handlers": ["mail_admins"],
            "level": "ERROR",
            "propagate": False,
        },
    },
}

Some can help me to figure out what's wrong with my logging configuration?

Are you calling logger.debug inside settings.py? I think that's the reason because that code is executed immediately when importing settings.py, and logging has not been configured yet. Try calling it in a view etc.
